# Using no tracking navigation property EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have 2 tables: Books and Authors. They are represented as following EF models:

```
class Book {
   Guid Id { get; set; }
   string BookName { get; set; }
   Author Author { get; set; }
}

class Author {
   Guid Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Both entities have autogenerated Guid Id, i.e. before being inserted into database, Ids are generated on client site(that's default behaviour of npgsql)
Book table has a foreign key to Author table.
So, lets say I have a several authors already. I would like to add new book by some author. It's a web app, so I have repositories injected into controller. Before inserting new book I load (readonly, i.e AsNoTracking for performance benefits) available authors, find required author and assign that author to newly created book's Author property. On DbContext.SaveChanges I got an error, saying the given Id already exist. I suspect EF is trying to add new Author with a given ID(even though it already exist in a database) because Author entity was loaded as NoTracking.

Is there a way to load foreign key as no tracking to create new entities?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of the `Add` method is to mark recursively as `Added` any *non tracked* entity discovered via navigation properties.

So you either has to `Attach` the existing related entities before calling `Add`, or use `Entry` method and set the `State` to `Added` - in EF6 this has the same effect as `Add`, but in EF Core it just marks the entity as `Added` without doing any navigation property processing.

e.g. the following will do what you are asking for:

```
var book = new Book { BookName = "SomeBook" };
book.Author = context.Authors.AsNoTracking().First(a => a.Name == "SomeAuthor");
context.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Added;
context.SaveChanges();
```