# How do I use non-tracked entities in navigation properties in EF Core 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, change-tracking, ef-core-7.0

I have a library that processes data from a database using Entity Framework Core 7. It returns entities to the client code, which puts them into navigation properties like this:

```cs
var newEntity = new SomeEntity {
  SomeProperty = "blah blah blah",
  SomeNavProperty = theLibrary.GetEntity()
};

theLibrary.Process(newEntity);  // Calls DbSet<TEntity>.Add
theLibrary.Save();  // Calls DbContext.SaveChanges
```

Everything works fine, but the sample method `GetEntity` returns a tracked entity, thus if the client code changes its properties, the changes will be persisted to the database as soon as `SaveChanges` is called, and I don't want such behavior. I tried returning a non-tracked entity from `GetEntity`:

```cs
public SomeAnotherEntity GetEntity() {
  return dbContext.SomeAnotherEntities.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
}
```

This resulted in an `SqlException` thrown by the `SaveChanges` method of the `DbContext`:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SomeAnotherEntities' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

So, how do I use non-tracked entities (from `AsNoTracking`) in navigation properties? In other words, how do I fix this exception? *Attaching the non-tracked related entity before calling `DbSet<TEntity>.Add` didn't work.*

### Code from the library

In fact, my class that works with database is generic. `TEntity` is the type of entity it works with. The `Process` method code:

```cs
public void Process(TEntity entity)
{
  int? id = (int?)typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("Id")?.GetValue(entity);
  if (id == null)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("No Id property");
  }
            
  if (id == 0) table.Add(entity);
  else
  {
    var tracked = table.Find(id);
    if (tracked == null) return;
                
    foreach (var property in tracked.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
      if (property.Name == "Id") continue;
      property.SetValue(tracked, property.GetValue(entity));
    }
  }
}
```

`table` is the `DbSet<TEntity>` (already fetched in the constructor) where entities of type `TEntity` are stored. The `Save` method just calls `SaveChanges`.

**`SomeEntity` definition, if needed to answer:**

```cs
public class SomeEntity {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
  public SomeAnotherEntity SomeNavProperty { get; set; }
}
```

### What I tried

In the Similar Questions block, there were two questions about the same issue as mine.

- [Using no tracking navigation property EF core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577692/using-no-tracking-navigation-property-ef-core) has one answer, which didn't work for me.
- [Do not track changes on navigation property in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75162812/do-not-track-changes-on-navigation-property-in-ef) has no answers, no solution in comments and seems to be non-answerable till the author adds their code.

Comment: Post the actual full exception text, not just the message part. LINQ queries don't generate INSERTs. Somehow, somewhere else your code is adding objects in the `Added` state. Those objects may have come from that query but EF or any other code doesn't know that. It only knows you attached that object in the `Added` state.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just told you I'm not attaching entities in `Added` state!

Comment: The facts disagree. If you attach *any* object, any related objects are also attached. If you use `Update` the actual state is controlled by the value of the PK/ID. If it's default, the object is attached in the Added state

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hmm OK, let me download my code and post it, and you see

Comment: To fix your problem you need to understand what your code is doing. And post the actual full exception text. That will show you *and us) where the error occurred and which calls led to it

Comment: And the entities I fetch using `AsNoTracking` — they're not in `Added` state, eh?

Comment: If you don't want to persist a property, mark it as `NotIncluded`. AsNoTracking doesn't have any effect on the object itself.

Comment: Why `NotIncluded`, I want the user to access all property. But not modify them. Or I don't understand?

Comment: `hey're not in Added state, eh` wrong - you're creating a new `SomeEntity` object so when *that* object is attached to the DbContext, all related objects, including the one stored in `SomeNavProperty` will also be attached and persisted.

Comment: `access all property. But not modify them` what are you trying to do? Are you saving that object before returning it to the client? In that case save it *before* setting the property you don't want to save.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Posted my code.

Comment: And "you're creating a new SomeEntity object so when that object is attached to the DbContext, all related objects, including the one stored in SomeNavProperty will also be attached and persisted." — no, I said in the question that I tried attaching the related entities (fetched using `AsNoTracking`). I set them to the `Unchanged` state, and the problem stayed.

Comment: The code shows you do call Add. So did your initial comments in the code. That means all objects are added in the `Added` state. If you thought that `AsNoTracking()` would produce un-attachable objects, you were wrong. You can easily set the property *after* saving though

Comment: `I set them to the Unchanged state, and the problem stayed.` not in the code you posted

Comment: But I tried it!

Comment: Set the property *after* saving. Your assumptions about what `AsNoTracking()` does are wrong.

Comment: "The code shows you do call Add." — I'm adding the new entity, not those fetched from `AsNoTracking`. Or you mean they are set to `Added` state, too?

Comment: Should I first add and save the new entity without setting navigation property, then set it, modify entity and save again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreign key property instead of navigation property while you creating entity

```cs
var entityId = theLibrary.GetEntity().Id;
var newEntity = new SomeEntity {
  SomeNavPropertyId = entityId,
  ...
};
```

It's simple and guarantees the expected behavior of non-tracked entity that the FK refers to

Is it acceptable in your case?

Comment: No, I can't use a foreign key because I need easy access to related entities for the client code (e.g. `theLibrary.GetEntity().SomeNavProperty.BlahBlahBlah`).

Answer (score 0):

The error is not at all related to the `AsNoTracking()` in EF core. Error is coming when you are trying to insert data into the database.

The reason is `Id` column in the table, is `Identity Column`, which means, the `Id` is automatically inserted by EF.

Ways to Solve this error:

1. You can set Identity Insert to OFF in your SQL table. [Identity Insert On/Off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
2. If you are passing `id` value, when Inserting the data into the database, i.e form Json. Just remove that value, as EF code will Automatically insert it.

Ex: If your json is as below:

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "name" : "TestName"
}
```

then change it to :

```
    {
      "name" : "TestName"
    }
```

That should work.

Comment: As you can see in the question, I don't set `Id` when initializing the `SomeEntity` instance. It is set to default value (i.e. zero) and thus automatically generated by the database. (Not by EF, by the way.) What about "You can set Identity Insert to OFF in your SQL table." — the exception message clearly says that IDENTITY_INSERT is already set to OFF!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "You explicitly attached those objects in the `Added` state." — wrong. I'm not adding entities *fetched* from the database. I'm just *linking* them to a completely new entity and then adding it.

Comment: @SNBS queries don't generate INSERTs. The exception is coming from somewhere else and telling you you added that object. `AsNoTracking()` means EF won't track those objects for changes, it doesn't mean they won't be inserted if you explicitly call `Add` or `Update` on them, or on a root

Comment: @SNBS PS post the entire error and the saving code. That's where the problem is